# CentOS 7: installed devtoolset-7, but GCC 7.8 is using GCC 4.8 installation's old C++ include files

Tags: centos, c++

I'm trying to compile and install [Pistache](http://pistache.io/) on a CentOS 7 machine, following their instructions.

This is a package that requires C++ 11, so since the Development Tools package on CentOS 7 installs an old version of gcc (4.8.3) that doesn't support C++ 11 features, I've installed devtoolset-7 and enabled it with `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash`.  This appears to be functioning properly, as `gcc --version` displays `gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)`.

However, when I try to `make` the Pistache sources, I get this compilation error:

```
/root/compiler_installation_script/pistache/src/server/router.cc:102:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_replace(const string&, std::regex&, const char [2])’
     SegmentTreeNode::multiple_slash, "/");
                                         ^
 /root/compiler_installation_script/pistache/src/server/router.cc:102:45: note: candidates are:
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/regex:62:0,
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding, this seems to indicate that my compiler is using outdated C++ include headers that are compatible with gcc 4.8.3, resulting in the error.  How can I fix this?

Note: I'm sure the issue isn't with Pistache source itself, as I've compiled this successfully on other machines, including a fresh CentOS 7 machine yesterday.

Comment: I had the same issue, in my case `rm -rf CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles` helped. I think first I only deleted CMakeCache.txt but maybe it wasn't enough

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  `cmake` was using an old version of gcc/g++, not the one that my command line was picking up when I ran `gcc` or `g++` myself.  So, I had to export CC and CXX to the appropriate paths before running cmake.

```
export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++
cmake3 -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Previously, I was only running the last line above.

Comment: You shouldn't need to export the C or C++ Compilter (CC or CXX). I've had devtoolset-7 in my CentOS 7 machine for a while (I also have GCC 8.2 which I compiled) and I've never had to export the compilers after running scl enable devtoolset-7 bash. When you `echo $PATH` and echo `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, do you get the paths to the executables and libraries such as: `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin`, `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib64`, and `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib`?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yup, the devtoolset-7 paths are showing up when I echo both $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I wonder if the cause is something related specifically to Pistache's cmake configuration.

Comment: I just compiled Pistache on my CentOS 7.5 machine after enabling `devtoolset-7` with the same command that you used. I was able to run the same `cmake3` command as you with the only difference being that I added `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=` to install it elsewhere. It finished and then I ran `make` and `make install` with no issues. It seems that there's something awry with your environment.

Comment: Yeah, definitely something specific to that box.  I did the same steps with a different, fresh CentOS 7 machine the other day and didn't encounter the issue.

Comment: Josh can you help me I have managed to compile Pistache in centos 6.5 and I have the library libpistache.a but when I try to compile a simple pistache program I get lots of errors like error expected before ; and about 30 other errors. Can you point me in the right direction?